# Python Scripting: remove animation from mesh/object

Tags: python, animation, scripting

Somehow? I seen `Remove Animation` action in action list(space), but was unable to call it on object I need. Console traced `Cancelled` so I think I did it wrong and called a ui method.

I seen `animation_clear()` method somewhere not sure if it's related

Answer (score 2):

```
obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
obj.animation_data_clear()
```

works fine, it seem to remove animation data, but doesn't update timeline immediately visually.